# grep 20k words from a file

Tags: grep

i have 5000 files in a folder. these files are named XX0000001 to XX0005000

i am trying to get words from each of these files, and grep them and the next line in another file (target.txt)

i have about 30,000 words in some of the XX* files

is there any way to do that ?

i have tried :

```
start_number=0000001
end_number=0005000
words_file=target.txt
output_folder="output_results"
mkdir -p "$output_folder"
for ((i=start_number; i <=end_number; i++)); do
   filename="XX$(printf "%07d" "$i")"
   output_file="$output_folder/output_${filename}.txt"
   while read -r word; do
      awk -v word="$word" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($1 ~ word) {print; next}}' "$filename" >> "$output_file"
   done < "$words_file"
done
```

is there a quicker way to do this ? my target file has millions of lines to search; precisely target file is 20 Gigabyte and 106441678 lines

for example:
XX0000001 file looks like:

```
Big1 Big5 Big7 Big10 Big11
```

(and many many more words to this; some XX files may even have up to 30k words)

Target.txt file looks like:

```
#Big1

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big2

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big3

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big4

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big5

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big6

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big7

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big8

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big9

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big10

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big11

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx

#Big12

This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx
```

Comment: What's the size (bytes and lines) of `target.txt`? Wondering if you could hold it in memory

Comment: Please provide a sample of one of the `XX` files and also of `target.txt`

Comment: target file is 20 Gigabyte and 106441678 lines

Comment: i have added the sample formats of the files in the original question

Comment: You mustn't add leading zeros to numbers you are going to perform arithmetic with, they will be treated as octal so here you will only count up to 2560.

Comment: i have files with upto 7 digits. i have asked this question only for the first 5000 files but in reality i will doing this for a very large number of files. so i have no option but to name the files with leading zeros.

Comment: You can name the file any how you want, it is the start and end values you are recording in variables and then using for arithmetic that are a problem. You will not process all your data. Example: `echo $((05000))`. But this is a side matter.

Comment: Kaur, "_i have added the sample formats of the files in the original question_" - do they really have so many blank lines? Format them as code and ensure they show correctly

Comment: @christ: there are no blank lines. i was not able to copy pase the format correctly in the question.

Comment: Your outer Bash (file) loop runs 5000, times, and each inner (read) loop 30,000 times, so you are running 150 million awk processes. awk can read multiple files, and reads lines efficiently. One of my clients wrote a similar script that was on target to run 30 days, and I got that down to 100 seconds (26,000 time faster) with awk.

Comment: Kaur if you can't show us a correct pair of example files it's unlikely people will be able to give you a properly working solution as they'll simply be guessing

Comment: Note you are also opening output_file (for append), and closing it again for every line of every input file, regardless of whether you actually write anything to it. You can avoid that by moving the redirect to after the `done`, or having the awk itself redirect conditionally.

Comment: See the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) (the question mark in the editing view, then "Advanced help"), the very first item tells about [code block formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code). Or see the [edit I made](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/766794/revisions) to your post to format the script as code (revision 2 in the list). It's really to try to give working solutions if one doesn't know exactly what the situation is, or what the data looks like.

Comment: Also, I would offer the opinion that the naming of your variables could be far clearer here. You say you're "trying to get words from the XX0*" files, but in your script, you have a variable called `words_file` that points at `target.txt`. That makes it somewhat unclear as to which file is supposed to contain the patterns to look for, and which file contains the data being searched for those patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have 5000 files in a folder. these files are named XX0000001 to XX0005000

To loop over a set of files, use shell globs, e.g. `for f in XX0*` here.
If you do need to loop over a set of numbers, you need to take care with the leading zeroes, as in Bash, they mark the number as octal. E.g. trying your loop but just printing the numbers and looking at the last one:

```
start_number=0000001
end_number=0005000
for ((i=start_number; i <=end_number; i++)); do
   echo $i
done |tail -1
```

We see the output is `2560`, not `5000`. This isn't the case in zsh, though, and you didn't mention which shell you're running, but nevertheless the issue might be worth pointing out.

---

Here,

```
   while read -r word; do
      awk -v word="$word" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($1 ~ word) {print; next}}' "$filename" >> "$output_file"
   done < "$words_file"
```

I'm not exactly sure what this is doing, but I'll just note that in the AWK script, you're looping over all fields of the input line, but then you only refer to field 1 (`$1`) within the loop.

---

Now, I'll assume your files look like this:

```
% cat XX0000001
Big1 Big7
% cat XX0000002
Big5 Big10
% cat target.txt
#Big1
This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx
#Big2
This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx
[...]
```

i.e. that there are multiple distinct patterns (e.g. `Big1` and `Big7`) in a single line in the `XX0*` files (and not e.g. one per line). Also, I suppose you want to find lines in `target.txt` that match any of the patterns and then print those along with the next line.

Now, standard grep can do the printing of "one more line" after a match, and it can look for multiple patterns at the same time. The `-f` option takes the name of a file whose lines form the patterns, so you'll have to preprocess your `XX0*` files to make each pattern appear as a single line. You can do that by changing all spaces to newlines with `tr`. It's easiest to use process substitution to have the output of `tr` available to `grep` as a file, but you could also use a temporary file (or maybe even pipe the output from `tr` to `grep -f -`)

e.g.:

```
% grep -A1 -f <(tr ' ' '\n' < XX0000001 ) target.txt
#Big1
This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx
--
#Big7
This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx
--
#Big10
This_is_a_file_containing_xxxxx
```

Of course, the pattern `Big1` also appears on the line `#Big10`, so it's matched. (But you could try the `-w` option to grep to ask for a full-word matching.) If you want to remove the `--` separators, you could pipe the result through `grep -ve --`.

How efficient that is may depend on your grep implementation, but being a tool made for the purpose, it likely has a better chance of being optimized than doing the same in a shell script would be. Shell scripts are slow. If all the patterns are of the format `Big*`, a smart move would be to look for the common part only once. Perhaps the list of patterns could be changed to a single one like `Big(1|5|7|10)` in the hope it works better for the regex engine.

Comment: the grep command you mention does work but fails after certain 2026 words for the first file itself.

Comment: @kaur, perhaps it might be worth looking at the exact data where it fails. Remove the parts where it _works_ from the data, and try to see what remains to isolate the issue. Look closer into the data to see if there's something amiss. Or post another question about it and it's likely someone is able to help you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a lot of search terms in a very big file, it's unlikely you will find a "quick" solution in shell/standard tools. That said, I think your approach is particularly inefficient.

Something like this, perhaps (untested):

```
words_file=target.txt
output_folder="output_results"
mkdir -p "$output_folder"
for filename in XX* ; do 
  output_file="$output_folder/output_${filename}.txt"
  grep -f "$filename" -Fx -A1 "$words_file" > "$output_file"
done
```

But I can't see this being quick either, frankly.

This could potentially be multithreaded, which might improve throughput.

Here is a multithreaded alternative. You will need to tune the `threads` value to something appropriate to your operating environment.

```
threads=4
words_file=target.txt
output_folder="output_results"
mkdir -p "$output_folder"

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'XX*' -print0 | \
  xargs -I% -0 -P$threads bash -c '
    file="%"
    output_file="$output_folder/output_${file#./}.txt"
    grep -f "%" -Fx -A1 "$words_file" > "$output_file"
  '
```

Any benefit from this is going to depend on hardware factors, such as available memory, number of CPU cores, and speed of storage, as well as others activity on the server.

Comment: i need to write the results in individual output files for each input file

Comment: Updated to paste in some of your code

Comment: Added a multi threaded version.

Comment: @bxm  I suspect you intended the single option `-print0`.

Comment: You're bang on Paul, thanks -- fixed.

Comment: I TRIED THSI WITH 4 FILES. 
it gives the folowing error: sh: line 2: /output_./XX0000002: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: /output_./XX0000001: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: /output_./XX2303090: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: /output_./XX0000003: No such file or directory

Comment: Ah sorry, small oversight -- hopefully fixed.

Comment: i tried the updated version, but now it gives me a new issue while creating new files in the outpur folder which did not happen with my original script. the error: sh: line 3: /output_FC0000002.txt: Permission denied
this did not happen with my initial script. i am clueless at this point

Comment: Sorry I used a small bit of bash specific syntax but not bash shell. Fixed the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear and you haven't provided any expected output which doesn't help clarify your requirements and makes it impossible to test a potential solution to see if it works or not but this MAY be what you want, using any awk:

```
awk '
    FILENAME != ARGV[ARGC-1] {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            words[$i]
        }
        next
    }
    f {
        print
    }
    {
        f = 0
        for ( word in words ) {
            if ( $0 ~ word ) {
                print
                f = 1
                next
            }
        }
    }
' some_folder/XX* target.txt
```

If you have so many `XX*` files that you exceed `ARG_MAX` then change it to:

```
printf '%s\n' some_folder/XX* |
awk '
    FILENAME == "-" {
        ARGV[ARGC++] = $0
        next
    }
    FILENAME != ARGV[ARGC-1] {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            words[$i]
        }
        next
    }
    f {
        print
    }
    {
        f = 0
        for ( word in words ) {
            if ( $0 ~ word ) {
                print
                f = 1
                next
            }
        }
    }
' - target.txt
```